# SSE4 instructions in VS2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, assembly, sse

I need to use the popcnt instruction in a project that is compiled using Visual Stdio 2005
The intrinsic `__popcnt()` only works with VS2008 and the compiler doesn't seem to recognize the instruction even when I write in a `__asm {}` block.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this is a wild guess thing but ... assuming you've set up VS2005 like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/3e24f203-c516-41e2-a7bf-325452157336/) to do assembly language, then you could get a hold of the [SSE4.1 manual](http://www.developers.net/filestore2/download/2550) from Intel and code a macro for each SSE4.1 opcode that you needed as per this [thread](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=973.0) at masm32.com (which discusses a similar issue w.r.t. SSE2.)

For example, here's some code out of one of the downloads from the masm32 link:

```
;SSE2 macros for MASM 6.14 by daydreamer aka Magnus Svensson

ADDPD MACRO M1,M2
    db 066h
    ADDPS M1,M2
ENDM

ADDSD MACRO M1,M2
    DB 0F2H
    ADDPS M1,M2
ENDM
```

Answer (score 2):

As a small note, you can use __emit to put bytes into __asm blocks in VC++. This is easier in a lot of cases than linking with masm produced objects. I used this in the past when SSE3 was new (and the opcodes were not supported in VS 2003).

All of the opcodes are [well documented by Intel](http://softwarecommunity.intel.com/isn/Downloads/Intel%20SSE4%20Programming%20Reference.pdf).